# Stacked area graph with ggplot gives sawtooth lines not solid polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to produce a stacked area graph using ggplot. Here is some code;

```
DATA <- data.frame("Band" = rep(c(1:10), each = 10), "Object" = rep(c("Tree", 
"Car", "Table", "Moon", "Tiger")), "Number" = runif(100, 1, 100), "Colour" = 
rep(c("Green", "Not Green"), each = 5))

ggplot(DATA, aes(x = Band, y = Number)) +
geom_area(aes(colour = Colour, fill = Colour), position = 'fill')
```

I end up with a bizarre "sawtooth" pattern, not two solid polygons. It doesn't matter if `Band` is an integer or numeric. If I treat `Band` as a factor, then I can get stacked lines, but with large gaps between them.

There are some similar questions here on SO; [Making a stacked area plot using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651428/making-a-stacked-area-plot-using-ggplot2) or [stacked area graph in ggplot2 returned as stacked lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434406/stacked-area-graph-in-ggplot2-returned-as-stacked-lines) but the answers suggested there don't seem to resolve my problem. I think I'm making a silly mistake, but I can't work out what it is. Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: in `geom_area`, try `position=stack`

Comment: Thanks @Ashish, but that just alters the height of the polygons, so that it is by 'Number' rather than proportion. The sawtooth pattern is the same though

Comment: so you want it by proportions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a silly mistake. The `Numbers` needed to be summarised to total counts within `Colour`, not left as individual values for each `Object`.

```
library(dplyr)
DATA <- DATA %>% group_by(Colour, Band) %>% summarise_at(.vars = "Number", funs(sum))
```

And then the `ggplot` code above works fine.